# Changing the contents of the New Tab page

Tags: chromium

How can I disable some sections of "New tab" contents in Chromium (not Chrome)?

Comment: But why would you want to do that?

Comment: this is an unneeded section with link. I want to fully control New Tab contents, in firefox it was about:blank

Comment: Also, it takes ages to load.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change new tab to about:blank in chrome without any extension](http://superuser.com/questions/774052/change-new-tab-to-aboutblank-in-chrome-without-any-extension)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the time to scratch up your own page there's a bunch of extensions that'll do what you want:

- [Custom new tab](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/jbnkijekempmdlleaimfelifcejbkmcd)
- [New Tab redirect](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/icpgjfneehieebagbmdbhnlpiopdcmna)
- [Incredible Startpage](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ncdfeghkpohnalmpblddmnppfooljekh)
- [Ultimate newtab](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/djnmanljkopakfofdpmelbccmbpbocaa)

[Et cetera](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/search?itemlang=&q=new+tab+page).

Comment: A lot of extensions breaks "Restore" functionality. Restore = restore opened tabs after crash. "New Tab" breaks it.

Comment: True. Best way perhaps is to change your homepage.

Comment: @digitxp, that doesn't work, at least as of Chromium 40.0.2214.91 Russian Fedora.