# Change new tab to about:blank in chrome without any extension

Tags: google-chrome

Can we change new tab to about:blank without installing any extension for latest chrome versions?

Comment: Not sure why question is marked duplicate. I want new tab to be blank and NOT chrome on startup.

Comment: Unfortunately, as many other options, chrome makes dictacy to you to like what they like, without leaving any option to you to customize.

Comment: This seems solution: **https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/set-aboutblank-as-new-tab/amcfcgenknhnhicjonfnclkehkpfnfjl**

Comment: Not enough rep to make an answer. You can use regedit "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome" - make a new String Value named "NewTabPageLocation" and set Value data to "about:blank"

Answer (score -1):

Yes.

1. Go to Chrome Settings
2. Change **On Startup** option to **Open a specific page or set of pages**.
3. Click on Set pages link
4. Set the page to *about:blank*

Comment: I am sorry! This may not work for a _New tab_. It's a startup option.

Comment: It is not working for new tab button. I tried that before posting question. Also, what if users have multiple pages set on startup (like me) ?